# Using Logging from Microsoft Application Block with WPF

Tags: wpf, logging

I have a WPF application and I want to use the Microsoft Application Block for logging (MIcrosoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging)

How can I configure it in order to work?

Comment: you're going to have to supply more information than that!

Answer (score 1):

It depends where and how you want to persist the log data.

Download the enterprise lib 4.1 from 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx

There is quick start for logging. The app.config within the sample is what you are after.
You shouldn't have to make much change from it in order to make your WPF logging works.

Answer (score 0):

FYI there's nothing special about using EntLib with a WPF application versus a WinForms or server application (assuming you're not launching forms for visual tracing).

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a document on this that should answer you question:

**Integrating the Logging Application Block with WCF Applications**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648685.aspx